# How to display NsMutable Array

Tags: ios, json, nsmutablearray, swift4

When decoding JSON response from webservice I get an ouput saying:

```
["dataresult": <__NSArrayM 0x1c0243090>( )]
```

How to display / decode this NSArrayM

Any help on this would be appreciated

Below is the code

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    print("JSON yet to be parsed")


                    if let parseJSON = json {


                        let myBoard = parseJSON["message"] as! [String:Any]

                        print("JSON parsed successfully !")
                        print(myBoard)

                        if let refResults = myBoard["dataresult"] as? [[String:String]]{
                            let valueArray = refResults.map {$0["Success"]!}


                            self.Contact = valueArray
                            print(self.Contact)



                        }
```

**Response from the Web Service:**

```
"message": {
"dataresult": [
  {
    "Success": "Success",
    "OwnerName": "test shop",
    "mobileno": "1231231231",
    "landline": "",
    "managername": "acsd acfacaf",
    "managerContact": "",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "website": "",
    "address": "gggysgyysusisss",
    "city": "hgyggg",
    "area": "fgatsbsuhsushsu",
    "pincode": "123123",
    "rentowned": "Leased",
    "homedelivary": "Yes",
    "working_start_time": "10.00 am",
    "working_end_time": "7.30 pm",
    "pwd": "123123"
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to make a loop in an array?

Comment: You can use `SwiftyJSONAccelerator` to handle JSON API Response. Here is link : https://github.com/insanoid/SwiftyJSONAccelerator

Comment: @zombie if we can implement the loop, that would be greater